# How can I echo a class? (Batch file)

Tags: batch-file

```
:PO1
cls
color a
echo on 1926 June 28th a baby was born,
echo a baby by the name of Zelda,
echo Zelda had a brother and a sister,
echo but soon this was all to be torn.
pause >nul

:PO2
Echo hello
Echo how u doing
Echo here
*echo PO1*
Pause >nul
```

(I apologise firstly if PO2 for example is not  a class, or called something else). Is it possible to echo everything under PO1?

Comment: You are looking for `heredoc`?

Comment: @jeb I basically want everything under PO1 to echo in PO2

Comment: ^Then you are looking for `heredoc` functionallity, you should simply find it

Comment: A terminology notice: There is nothing like classes in batch-files. It’s a [non-structured programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-structured_programming)! Things like `:PO1` are just [labels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Label_(computer_science)).

Comment: @Melebius thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch files are executed top-down sequentially.

When you want to transfer execution point to another part of the batch file, you must use `call :label` or `goto :label`. `call` jumps to the given label and returns when finds an `exit /B` or `goto :eof` command. `goto` jumps to the given label and continues from that point. It doesn't return.

So any series of commands between `:label` and `exit /B` is what we call a `function` or `subroutine` depending if it returns a value or not.

May be something like this?

```
@echo off

:PO2
echo This is in PO2, but not seen because of PO1 cls 
call :PO1
echo Back again in PO2, this will be echoed after PO1 pause

exit /B

:PO1
cls
color a
echo on 1926 June 28th a baby was born,
echo a baby by the name of Zelda,
echo Zelda had a brother and a sister,
echo but soon this was all to be torn.
pause >nul
exit /B
```

The main branch is from `@echo off` to the first `exit /B`. Now `PO1` is a `function or subroutine` which can be called from anywhere. Note the `exit /B` at the end.

`exit /B` means exit the current function (from a previous call), or the batch itself (without call or goto). BTW you may also return a numeric value, i.e  `exit /B 1`

> EDIT: again

```
:PO2
Echo hello
Echo how u doing
Echo here
Pause >nul
call :PO1
exit /B  

:PO1
cls
color a
echo on 1926 June 28th a baby was born,
echo a baby by the name of Zelda,
echo Zelda had a brother and a sister,
echo but soon this was all to be torn.
pause >nul
exit /B
```

NOTE `PO1` is ended with `exit /B`. The `echo P01` changed to `call :PO1` and `pause` moved one line up as `cls` in `PO1` will clear the screen.

Comment: So it sort of works. I have a PO1 in my code as well as a PO2. I want PO1 to be echoed, which worked as you showed. But I want PO2 to be showed as well. Do you understand like what I mean?

Comment: is it possible to call it before anything?

Comment: the edit has it after, is it possible to get it before?

Comment: @AidenTooMLG see edit. Still don't know what's your goal!! really vey little information. Please again read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This site is not a source code wiriting service. You' ve to tell us your efforts, where are you getting stuck, what is the real question, and then people may help you at that point.

Comment: I am a really basic batch coder, I just started, so I will take your advice, but if you explain what you write down it would help too.

Comment: @AidenTooMLG. I've edited post again. it now includes brief information. a good starting point [Getting started with batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.phphttp://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php) or [DOS Batch - Function Tutorial](http://www.dostips.com/DtTutoFunctions.php). also open a cmd window and type help.